# Including a cloned repo in a git repo

Tags: macos, git, github

I'm writing an app in xcode, and I'm using git (though using the github app to commit and manage it, not xcode) for version control.
I use PXSourceList in the project, which I've cloned to my computer. I include the files as references in Xcode, so this means they aren't part of my git repo which syncs to github. So if someone were to download or clone from github they wouldn't be able to build without getting PXSourceList themself. How do I include PXSourceList, so that it is "referenced" in my repository?

Both on my computer (to my local clone) and on github (to PXSourceList on github)? So that PXSourceList will stay up to date in my repo when changes are made to it by others independant of my repo?

Comment: This might be of some help http://www.rubyinside.com/giternal-easy-git-external-dependency-management-1322.html

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813030/how-can-i-have-linked-dependencies-in-a-git-repo

Answer (score 0):

Subrepo or git-subtree. You have to move PXSourceList into your project tree in both cases