# How to use another git repo as my existing repo's dependency

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

Say I have an existing git repo I am working on named - b2c, give it an URL https://github.com/XXX/angular-portal-b2c.git

I have another git repo called b2c-library, which contains the useful pre-build library.  URL: https://github.com/XXX/angular-portal-library.git

I want to be able to use b2c-library in my b2c project, just like a dependency, which in node_modules, it should have a folder called b2c-library.

What steps should I follow?

Thanks.

As I said, it should just like a dependency which should appear in your node_modules. **when you do npm install, the b2c-library should be installed in node_modules**, git status should not track anything you did in b2c-library even you are in that repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I have linked dependencies in a git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813030/how-can-i-have-linked-dependencies-in-a-git-repo)

Answer (score 1):

So you want this to work like a node dependency... that seems much more like an `npm` question than a `git` question.

In your package.json you can specify the library as a dependency, using the git URL in place of the normal version string.  See the relevant `npm` documentation at https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Or, if you don't want to have to maintain the version relationship via the commit-ish in the URL, you can package the lib and put it in a private NPM registry.  In that case, you of course have to load updated versions of the lib into the registry before the other package can "see" it.