# GitHub Cloning sub projects Separately

Tags: git, github

I would like to have a multi module project in GitHub where each sub module can be clones separately. For example.,

```
my_project
 -- project-1
 -- project-2
```

So each of those project should have a separate clonable GitHub url and at the same time if I would like to clone the entire repository, I could do so with cloning the top level my_project.

I'm not sure how to do this. I came across submodules and I'm not suite sure if this is the right thing.

All I understand about sub-modules is that I can attach an already existing repository to be part of my other repository. Is this correct? But I want to be able to create new repository from within my top project. Any ideas on where to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind are dependencies (your submodules). [Here is how they are used (SO post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813030/how-can-i-have-linked-dependencies-in-a-git-repo)  and [here is how they work internally (git documentation)](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

For seperate GitHub URLs you would need seperate projects/ repositories wich you couldn´t clone at once (execpt with a script...).

Maybe you could think about hosting your own git server and manage it that you can download every single sub-repo with a specific url and all at once with another url. I think -not tested- you could do this by file structure like you mentioned:

```
my_project (git repo)
 -- project-1 (git repo)
 -- project-2 (git repo)
```