# Wrong git branch loaded in node_modules by yarn install command

Tags: reactjs, typescript, git, yarnpkg, package.json

I have two Typescript projects.

**Context**:
ProjectA depends upon a certain ProjectB branch project

**ProjectB git branches**:

1. `main`
2. `new_branch`

**ProjectA package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@projectB": "git+https://github.com/projectB.git#new_branch",
}
```

**What I want to achieve?**
When I execute `yarn install` to make sure that the dependencies from the `new_branch` are loaded in `node_modules` folder of `projectA`.

**What actually happens?**
When I execute `yarn install`, the dependencies from `main` branch are loaded.

**What I tried?**

1. I deleted `node_modules` & `build` folders and tried to run `yarn install` again which did not work.
2. I deleted `yarn.lock` but the project split another errors that are not related to my changes from the `new_branch` at all.
3. I deleted the `@projectB`: `git+https://github.com/projectB.git#new_branch` dependency from the `package.json` file and I added it via `yarn add projectB@git+https://github.com/projectB.git#new_branch` which did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the ability to have an npm dependency to a git branch. Maybe its possible but normally you would publish that git repo to an npm repository. Or you can reference the 'main' file like this:

## Solution 1 - Import from locally installed npm project

**repo1/package.json**

```
  "files": [
    "dist" // the generated production output from this repo
  ],
  "main": "dist/index.umd.js",
```

You would also have to install npm packages in both repos for this to work.

**repo2/package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@otherrepo": "file:../repo1"
   }
```

**repo2/index.js**

```
import otherrepo from '@otherrepo'

// do stuff with other repo
```

Note for this solution you would need to configure the the alias @otherrepo in webpack or equivalent.

Not sure if this is what you are after but this is an example I created using 2 repos (webpack and microbundle)
The webpack example loads the output from the microbundle as a dependency

https://github.com/inspiraller/webpack-and-microbundle

## Solution 2 - publish your git repo to npm

Once you are happy with your development cycle you can publish repo 1 to the npm repository and then you can just install it like any other npm package.

## Solution 3 - Use git submodules:

Answered here:
[How can I have linked dependencies in a git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813030/how-can-i-have-linked-dependencies-in-a-git-repo)

I'm sure the technology here has advanced, but when I played with it I discovered too many pitfalls of caching and reinstalling.

## Solution 4 - load shared components via an external managed cdn

This is for React but there are probably alternatives to other frameworks

- https://harmony-docs.bit.dev/tutorials/build-and-share-components/
- https://bit.dev/

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you should prefix the branch name with either `#branch=new_branch` or `#head=new_branch`. Additionally if you wanted to use a particular workspace, you could append that to the URL as well:

```
https://github.com/projectB#branch=new_branch&workspace=@projectB/workspace-you-want-to-install-from-new_branch
```

Another way to link things in a more specific way is to do a commit SHA:

```
https://github.com/projectB#commit=f4f78b319c308600eab015a5d6529add21660dc1&workspace=@projectB/workspace-you-want-to-install-from-that-commit-sha
```

If at anytime you need to troubleshoot, you should search your `yarn.lock` to understand what the `package.json` is being resolved to under `resolution`.